# COVID-19: Medical imaging recommendations from Asia

Tags: covid-19, medical-imaging, ct-scans, guidelines

Since the demand for imaging is increasing regarding COVID-19 and the number of papers describing COVID-19 patterns in computed tomography (CT) is increasing, I searched medical imaging recommendations/guidelines for the clinical routine.

**What I found**:

Besides the American College of Radiology (ACR) [recommendation regarding COVID-19 and imaging](https://www.acr.org/Advocacy-and-Economics/ACR-Position-Statements/Recommendations-for-Chest-Radiography-and-CT-for-Suspected-COVID19-Infection), I found similar recommendations (mostly from European Radiological societies), e.g.:

- [STR](https://thoracicrad.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/STR-ASER-Position-Statement-1.pdf)
- [RCR](https://www.rcr.ac.uk/college/coronavirus-covid-19-what-rcr-doing/rcr-position-role-ct-patients-suspected-covid-19)
- [BSTI](https://www.bsti.org.uk/media/resources/files/COVID11.3.20_2.pdf)
- [RANZCR](https://www.ranzcr.com/our-work/coronavirus)

I assume that especially countries in Asia might have a lot of experience. However, I could not find any source.

**What I am looking for**:

Is there any medical imaging recommendation/guideline regarding COVID-19 from an Asian Radiological Society?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about official Chinese recommendations, but this might help.

China had experience with SARS, and this new infection was looking a lot like SARS. They did not have a surfeit of testing kits for a new virus, but they knew what SARS looked like on CT scans. Therefore, symptomatic patients received CT scans of the chest *before being tested for coronavirus*. If it was positive for the new pattern of atypical pneumonia, they were *then* tested and triaged.

Since then, we have developed other screening tests that do not involve CT scans.

See [here](https://www.bioworld.com/articles/433530-china-uses-ai-in-medical-imaging-to-speed-up-covid-19-diagnosis) and [here](https://www.contagionlive.com/news/ct-scans-provide-covid19-insight) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good overview of medical imaging recommendations for COVID-19 from many radiological societies.

https://www.myesr.org/covid-19-resources > Guidance for radiologists in dealing with COVID-19 patients > By country.

Unfortunately, I could still find no recommendations from Asian radiological societies.